# Flesch Program c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that calculates the score of a text file (Flesch) by counting the words, sentences, and syllables in a program and right now I'm having trouble having by bool functions be declared after a write code for each one. Here's what I got:
￼

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int numSentences, numWords, numSyllables; //for alphabet A-Z, a-z....unexpected    unqualified0id before 'int'
int isalpha(char isWordStarting);
bool inSentence, inWord, inSyllable;//


inSyllable(char isSyllableStarting);{//error: expected constructor, destructor, or    type conversion before ; token....
if (numSyllables = 'a','e','i','o','u'){//error: unqualified id before '{' token => inSyllable function
return true;}
  inSyllable(char isSyllableEnding);{
else {
return false;
}

      inWord(char isWordStarting);{
if(numWords = isalpha(char isWordStarting)){
  return true;}
   inWord(char isWordEnding);{
  else {
return false;
   }

       inSentence(char isSentenceStarting);{
   if(numSentences = '.',';',':','!','?'){
   return true;
   }
   inSentence(char isSentenceEnding);{
   else{
   return false;
   }
 int main (int argc[1], char*argv[]) {
   char c;
   ifstream infile;
   infile.open(agrv[1]);
   while (not (infile.eof());{ //start of loop
          infile.get(c);
          cout.put(c);

          for(int numSentences=0; numSentences < argc; numSentences++) { //Sentences
          cout << numSentences << ": " << argv[numSentences] << endl;
          }

          for(int numWords=0; numWords < argc; numWords++){ //Words
          cout << numWords << ": " << argv[numWords] << endl;
          }

          for(int numSyllables=0; numSyllables < argc; numSyllables++) {//Syllalbles
          cout << numSyllables << ": " << argv[numSyllables] << endl;
          }
          }
          infile.close(); //close file
          return 0;
          }
```

Any ideas? I put annotations next to the lines I'm having problems with.

Comment: `if (numSyllables = 'a','e','i','o','u')`  This doesn't do what you think it does...

Comment: Based on your question, I'd suggest working through a basic C++ tutorial or two to get more comfortable with the syntax. A couple of hits off of Google: http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ and http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c++-tutorial.html. Then try some simple programs on your own and work your way up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon on the first error line :)

Instead of a function definition, the semi colon makes it an attempted function call followed by braces which doesn't make sense - its confusing the compiler.

```
inSyllable(char isSyllableStarting);{ //This one here.
```

Also note that it should have a return type.  Its looking for a constructor because your function definition has none.

---

**More Errors:** You have more wrong here than just that.  For example, if you space your current code well at the error location, you get this mess:

```
inSyllable(char isSyllableStarting);
{
    if (numSyllables = 'a','e', 'i', 'o', 'u'){
        return true;
    }
    inSyllable( char isSyllableEnding);
    {
        else{
            return false;
        }
```

**So, here's a list of problems:**

1. Semi colon shouldn't be there on top line before function brace open.
2. Your if is followed by a recursive call to your function instead of the else which is mistakenly further down.
3. Your braces don't add up - this function never ends from the code above.

Comment: He should also check his if and else's. Seems to be very wrong.

Comment: Yeah there's a number of confusing things here :/ this'll move on to the next error at least.

Comment: @Named "very wrong" is quite generous.

Comment: Yea, I'm also a bit confused about the if/else statements I'm supposed to use.

Comment: @w00te Thanks for the help. I removed a lot of the semi colons that weren't supposed to be there and "fixed" the if/else statement.